# Is there a way to build a customer growth model in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, math, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have this problem where I want to create a customer growth model based on how many new customers sign up for our service. I have the number of new signups in one row and the estimated revenue we earn for each customer on each week.

[image: What I'm looking for]

Meaning: I want to take the new customer (or **customers**!) going live that week and have them start generating revenue based on the model above. I know the week number but I can't figure out a smooth way to have this sum up nicely.

What I don't want is a formula where for every new week I have to append the formula with `each new customers going live column * W0 of the revenue model`

I.e. this is a bit messy if I would do for 100+ columns: `=$F$24*K$22+$J$24*G$22+$M$24*D$22`

[image]

**Is there a better way to write these kinds of models?**

Here's an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cb8k3a-ydVAWx8air4W3AtpfOHk7sosLGh4VNgStMIM/edit#gid=930057993

Comment: how is calculated 8450 ? share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: It's not clear for me what is the expected behavior here. Can you provide a sample data structure, clearly specifying what is your desired output?

Comment: Here it is! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cb8k3a-ydVAWx8air4W3AtpfOHk7sosLGh4VNgStMIM/edit#gid=930057993

Comment: Why do formulas start only at week 3?

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part is that new customers need values from week 0, then week 1 and so on, and new customers in other weeks start from 0 again.
To make it easier to calculate, you can add lines with the number of the week and the correspondent value for each new customer(s) and sum them. Like this:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| week: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| revenue model: | 2500 | 2600 | 2700 | 2800 | 2900 | 2950 | 3000 | 3150 | 3200 | 3800 | 4000 | 4100 |
| new customers: | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| cumulative: | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| revenue: | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2500 | 2600 | 2700 | 2800 | 5400 | 5550 | 5700 | 10950 | 13800 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| week per new customers: |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| revenue per customers: |  |  |  | 2500 | 2600 | 2700 | 2800 | 2900 | 2950 | 3000 | 3150 | 3200 |
| week per new customers: |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| revenue per customers: |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2500 | 2600 | 2700 | 2800 | 2900 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5000 | 5200 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2500 |

You can check my solution here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dbz31Q_2B-7nG2VvuBXG2-xasvZRa3RPsjtEX7dH2O8

How I did it:

For the first line of "week per new customers:", the first cell (B7 in the example) only checks if the "new customers" cell is greater than 0:

```
=IF(B$3>0,0,)
```

It stays empty if zero, and changes to 0 otherwise (meaning week 0).

Copy the formula to the second cell (C7) and change to also check if the previous cell is not empty, adding 1 in this case:

```
=IF(B7<>"",B7+1,IF(C$3>0,0,))
```

Copy the cell to the rest of the line.
For the first "revenue per customers:" line, find the value that corresponds to the number of the calculated week and multiply by the number of added customers (found on line 3, subtracting the number of the week to find the column):

```
=IF(B7="",,INDEX($B$2:$2,1,B7+1)*OFFSET(B$3,0,-B7))
```

Copy to the rest of the line.

For the second line of "week per new customers:", the first cell stays empty. The second (C9) can be copied from 2 above (C7), but then the formula must be adapted to also check if C7 is empty or zero, remaining empty in such case:

```
=IF(C7=0,,IF(B9<>"",B9+1,IF(C$3>0,0,)))
```

Testing if C7=0 returns TRUE not only if the number in C7 is zero, but also if it's an empty cell.
Copy the cell to the rest of the line.

Then, select the content of the first line of "revenue per customers:" and the second of "week per new customers:" (lines 8 and 9) and drag to autocomplete the next lines.

Finally, calculate the revenue (5th line) with this formula on cell B5:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B7:B, MOD(ROW(B7:B)+MOD(ROW(B7),2),2) )
```

It sums only the even lines starting from B7. It works multiplying the numbers of the matrix B7:B by a matrix with 0's and 1's (rest of the division of the number of the row by 2, but first adding this rest for the row of first cell, to guarantee it'll start the 1's from the second line) and summing everything.
Copy to the rest of the line and that's all. The result will be as the table above.

Notice that I changed your example to have 2 new customers at week 10, so we can also check the validity for more than one customer in the same week.